# Delphi 2009 documentation

Tags: delphi, documentation, delphi-2009

does the new Delphi IDE (2009) come with some documentation ? (kind of like the MSDN with VS).
where can you get it ? (want to have a look at it)

is the documentation good ?

i picked up a copy of Delphi in 21 days . is it good for beginners in Delphi ?

Comment: Did you install Delphi and then somehow not find the Help? Or are you wanting to read the Help before you buy?

Comment: Please move your second question (about "Delphi in 21 Days") to a separate post. Asking multiple unrelated questions in a single post just muddies the waters. You can post as many questions as you want, and you can get more points by collecting up-votes on all of them instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all available from the Embarcadero website here: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/ in CHM (WinHelp) / PDF / HTML format.  (I don't know whether it's any good or not.)

Comment: There are a lot of stubs in it.  But it's getting better and they update it a lot (gigantic >100 MB updates)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [public wiki](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Wiki) which was started sometime back by Nick Hodges (the *then* product manager of Delphi). Not sure about the quality of contents though!

About the book: It is not exactly answer of your question but try grabbing Mastering Delphi by [Marco Cantu](http://www.marcocantu.com/). Its really the best book I have read on Delphi.

Comment: AFAIK, Nick Hodges is still Delphi product manager.

Comment: Nick now is the R&D Manager on the RAD Studio, his position changed two months ago.

Comment: You can get Mastering Delphi as a PDF (albeit unprintable) if you purchase Delphi 2009, so it's kinda like documentation.

Comment: Peter, you actually get Delphi 2009 Handbook as PDF if you are a registered user of the product (and at the moment also with the RAD Studio Trial version)

Comment: how could you say otherwise about the book, ITS THE ONLY BOOK ABOUT DELPHI.

Answer (score 1):

One cool thing about Delphi 2009 is that they load the summary tags written above each function in the hint you get when you mouse over your source.  It's the same thing you'd get if you hit F1, but that saves a click and a wait.